# ServiceStack with ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: webforms, servicestack

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application and I want to run ServiceStack alongside it. Lets say the application's URL is ~/Web. I have read the ServiceStack tutorial at http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/.

Since my app is not MVC, I followed the installation of ServiceStack at the root "/" path. I have successfully configured ServiceStack and now displays the metadata when I use URL `~/Web/metadata`.

But the problem is, when going to the default URL `~/Web`, it serves default.htm page in which it should be serving to Default.aspx.

Inline questions:

- Can I configure ASP.NET Webforms to go back to Default.aspx than the
  newly added (by the nuget installation of ServiceStack) default.htm?
- If I remove the default.htm file, the default URL `~/Web` would route
  to `~/Web/metadata`. Even if I use `~/Web/Default.aspx`, it would
  still route to `~/Web/metadata`. Any workaround to make Default.aspx
  work as well?
- Should I be using the custom path (eg: `~/Web/api`) instead?

Please let me know if the question is not clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question is asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/fOivqe_tsa8) and answered by myth. I will copy it here:

> In order to run ASP.NET you need to host servicestack on a different path, e.g. /api or /servicestack
>   See the b) web.config example on http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/
>
> You can view a static default.htm page but to run an .aspx page the request needs to go to ASP.NET.